# How to show the intersection of arbitrary compact sets is compact in a general metric space?

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I understand that if you are working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then the intersection of an arbitrary collection of compact sets is compact because it is closed and bounded. But what if you are not in $\mathbb{R}^n$? How can you show that the intersection of arbitrary compact sets in a general metric space is compact?

This is homework so I only need a hint. Thank you!

Comment: Which definition of compactness are you meant to use? The sequential definition should be very easy (if you have a sequence in the intersection, then it is a sequence in one of the compact subsets, also recall that the intersection of arbitrary closed subsets of a metric space is itself closed and hence contains its limit points). The open covering definition should also be pretty easy but you maybe need to think a bit more cleverly about how to extend an open covering of your intersection to one of the compact subsets.

Comment: I'm going to read up on that, thank you!

Comment: A quick note. You will need to use somewhere that, in metric spaces, compact subsets are always closed. This is a consequence of metric spaces being Hausdorff. The reason is that, in non-Hausdorff spaces, the statement in your question is not true in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metric Spaces are Hausdorff, so compact sets are closed. Now, arbitrary intersection of closed sets are closed. So for every open cover of the intersection, we can get an extension to a cover for the whole metric space. Now just use the definition.

Comment: That's the part I'm having trouble with, mathematically explaining how to create an extension that covers the whole original union of compact sets. How would you create one?

Comment: @AllisonCameron Let $X$ be compact and $C\subseteq X$ closed. Suppose $\{U_i\}$ is an open cover of $C$. Then by definition we have $U_i=U_i'\cap C$ for all $i$ where $U_i'$ is some open subset of $X$. Thus $\{U_i'\}\cup \{X\setminus C\}$ is an open cover of $X$, so...

Comment: @AlexBecker Thank you! I'm just a little confused still...you use the subspace topology to write $U_i=U_i'\cap C$ for each $U_i$, and I think (but am not sure) that you are saying that each $U_i$ is open in some subspace of X, correct? Which subspace? And how do you know this? Isn't it each $U_i$ just open in X to start with?

Comment: @AllisonCameron Each $U_i$ is open in $C$ (that's how I defined them), which is a subspace of $X$.

Answer (score 7):

Hint: A closed subset of a compact set is compact. What do you know about compact sets in Hausdorff spaces?

Answer (score 4):

Are you using the sequential compactness definition?  Any sequence in the intersection will be a sequence in any one of those particular compact sets, say $A$, in the intersection.  This has a convergent subsequence in $A$ and since the intersection of closed sets is closed (and compact sets are closed in metric spaces), this same subsequence must converge in the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\{x(n)\}$ be any sequence in the intersection of compact subspaces of $X$. Then $\{x(n)\}$ is a member of every compact subspace individually. Compact spaces are closed in general hence every subspace contains the limit of the sequence. Now since arbitrary intersection of closed sets is closed this implies that the intersection is also closed. Hence $n$ contains the limit of $\{x(n)\}$ and hence converges. Since $\{x(n)\}$ is any general sequence in the intersection which converges (hence has a convergent subsequence) makes it compact by the sequential criteria. 
This approach seems good for your homework.